# Akamai Web service to show custom graph

Tags: web-services, akamai

I want to take akamai data and show graph in my way. I tried to find their API but i didn't find it. Have you any idea? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Services and API Development user guide isn't available publicly. If you have access to Akamai's Customer Control Panel, you should be able to find all the information you need. Let me know if you need guidance there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i have access Akamai's customer control panel. but where i found that api so that i can access my reports?

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in to the Luna Control Center, a list of available web services is available at

https://control.akamai.com/portal/content/akaServiceSupport/documentation/EdgeControlWebServicesDocumentation.jsp

Comment: Thanks a lot for share your experience.